# Add members to guilds with OAuth2 and Discord.js

Tags: oauth-2.0, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to figure out how to add a member to a guild using Discord.JS and OAuth2. Any help would be appreciated.

A guide/further instructions would also be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Read more about oauth2 here: [Getting started with OAuth2](https://discordjs.guide/oauth2/#getting-started-with-oauth2)